# Send datas from front to back in Javascript and Express

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

I created a variable to catch data from my frontend and want to retrieve it in my Express backend.

My js variable and POST request:

```
const dataPush = {
                urlSave: urlSave,
                imgSave: imgSave,
                marqueSave: marqueSave,
                smSave: smSave,
                typeSave: typeSave,
                precisionSave: precisionSave,
                yearsSave: yearsSave,
                coteEuSave: coteEuSave,
                coteUsdSave: coteUsdSave,
                coteGbSave: coteGbSave,
                coteChfSave: coteChfSave
            }
            let postIdUrl = String('/fr/post')
            fetch(postIdUrl, {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({"data": "dataPush"}),
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
            })
            console.log(dataPush)
```

And it's okay, I get all the data I need.

My Express code:

```
router.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    console.log('yep !')
});
```

How to retrieve data from the `dataPush` variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fetch request. Remove quotation marks on variable being passed and perhaps pass as JSON

```js
fetch(postIdUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ "data": dataPush }),
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
})
```

Your endpoint

```js
router.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
});
```